# Why can't python find this function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Solution:
        
    def traverseT(s: TreeNode, t: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if (s.val == t.val):
            return traverseT(s.left, t.left) or traverseT(s.right, t.right)
        else:
            return traverseT(s.left, t) or traverseT(s.right, t)
        
    def isSubtree(self, s: TreeNode, t: TreeNode) -> bool:
        return traverseT(s, t)
```

The error I get is

```
NameError: name 'traverseT' is not defined
    return traverseT(s, t)
Line 16 in isSubtree (Solution.py)
```

I have zero idea what is wrong. Any suggestions? It seems to be correct... The function is declared before, and in the same class.

Comment: You forgot `self.`

Comment: That being said, you're not showing how you actually call the code.

Comment: Where do I need to put self? def traverseT(self, s: TreeNode, t: TreeNode)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist OP shows where the code is called, it's right there in `isSubtree`.

Comment: @AlanLiddell. No, that's a class definition with two method definitions in it. Neither method is called. Put it another way, there are 10 lines shown, but the error is on line 16

Comment: @MadPhysicist if we agree that the trouble OP is having is missing the `self` keyword, then you can extrapolate from there that the call to `traverseT` in `isSubtree` is the attempt to call the instance method. Where `isSubtree` is called doesn't really seem to be relevant.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Just to add some clarity, lines 1-6 are commented code. So line 16 is effectively line 10 in the snippet I posted.

Comment: @AlanLiddell. Agreed. Teaching OP to post a proper question is orthogonal to answering the one at hand, but in my opinion just as important

Comment: @MadPhysicist fair enough, agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`traverseT` is an instance method, so should be invoked as `self.traverseT`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sri if this answer was useful, please feel free to accept it. :^)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
return self.traverseT(s, t)
```